# How To Set A Standalone Attachment Content Type

Tags: file-upload, couchdb, couchapp

I've been able to create a standalone attachment, but the content_type ends up as multipart/form-data. What I am I doing wrong? The code is followed by the response from the post and then the request; you can see in the request that the content type is correct in the Request Payload.

Code:

```
 function uploadFile() {
    var fd = new FormData();
    var file = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0];
    fd.append("fileToUpload", document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0]);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);
    xhr.open("PUT", "http://usr:pswd@localhost:5984/db_test/testdoc7/"+ file.name +"?rev=1-967a00dff5e02add41819138abb3284d");

    xhr.send(fd);
  }
```

Response:

```
{
   "_id": "testdoc7",
   "_rev": "2-2841dcd640adb94de525e486be34052e",
   "_attachments": {
       "P9025287.JPG": {
           "content_type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary9QNXLDTeW13Gc1ip",
           "revpos": 2,
           "digest": "md5-VcoscthaPUYoWHBmCBaAnA==",
           "length": 3083669,
           "stub": true
       }
   }
}
```

Request:

```
Request URL:http://usr:pswd@localhost:5984/db_test/testdoc7/P9025287.JPG?rev=1-967a00dff5e02add41819138abb3284d
Request Method:PUT
Status Code:201 Created
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:3083669
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary9QNXLDTeW13Gc1ip
Cookie:AuthSession=YmRyaG9hOjUwOUFFNDg3OnR23NsQsqdQvnKp7HX_0g90grXw
Host:localhost:5984
Origin:http://localhost:5984
Referer:http://localhost:5984/estante_test/_design/library/html5/html5test.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11
Query String Parametersview URL encoded
rev:1-967a00dff5e02add41819138abb3284d
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundary9QNXLDTeW13Gc1ip
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileToUpload"; filename="P9025287.JPG"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundary9QNXLDTeW13Gc1ip--
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:must-revalidate
Content-Length:71
Content-Type:text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 07 Nov 2012 22:45:40 GMT
ETag:"2-2841dcd640adb94de525e486be34052e"
Location:http://localhost:5984/estante_test/testdoc7/P9025287.JPG
Server:CouchDB/1.2.0 (Erlang OTP/R15B)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is PUT'ing the body of an entire form to CouchDB. I suspect if you look at the attachment, you'll find that not just the Content-Type is incorrect. Something like this should work better:

```
function uploadFile() {
  var file = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0];
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
  xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
  xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
  xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);
  xhr.open("PUT", "http://usr:pswd@localhost:5984/db_test/testdoc7/"+ file.name +"?rev=1-967a00dff5e02add41819138abb3284d");
  xhr.send(file);
}
```

This works because the File interface inherits from Blob, so the [XHR2 send algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-send-method) will submit the file's raw data as well as setting the mime type based on the your file entry's .type attribute.

Note that at least some browsers do not provide a good MIME type guess for files, so you may still end up with "application/octet-stream" as the type unless you provide an override for yourself via [xhr.setRequestHeader()](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader-method).